# Merge this inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my OOP function in JavaScript where I use library with callback.

Code looks like:

```
$('body').mCustomScrollbar({
  theme: 'minimal',
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      console.log(this.mcs.draggerTop);
    }
  }
});
```

Inside callback function (whileScrolling) I have this.mcs (made by library). But I dont have access to my OOP function variables.
If I want to get access to them, I have to do

```
whileScrolling: function() {
  console.log(this.mcs.draggerTop);
}.bind(this);
```

If I do that, I get access to all by this. variables (on OOP function), but I loose every variable on old this inside callback, so I no longer have this.mcs.draggedTop.

Is there any way to "merge" this-es (previous one + new one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the value of the outer `this` to a variable and use that variable inside the callback:

```
var outerThis = this;                              // the outer this
$('body').mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: 'minimal',
    callbacks: {
        whileScrolling: function() {
            // here this is the inner this
            // and outerThis is the outer this
            console.log(this.mcs.draggerTop);
        }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  $('body').mCustomScrollbar({
 theme: 'minimal',
 self:this,
callbacks: {
   whileScrolling: function() {
  console.log(self.localVariable);
 }
}
})
```

Comment: that's not valid javascript

Comment: You can't declare variables inside an object literal

Comment: I didn't realise it as object...:(